# Trouble extracting search result links using Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the search result links from this website: https://www.dtcc.com/search?q=aggregated%20transaction%20data and when I use your typical Beautiful Soup to get "a" and "href" it doesn't seem to pick up the links to each of the ~100 or so search results. How can I get these search result links? Thanks!

Here is the code that I have tried. I seem to only be able to find other scripts that work off variations of this, and aren't able to pick up the search result links.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

search_url = "https://www.dtcc.com/search?q=aggregated%20transaction%20data"
page = requests.get(search_url)    
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all(attrs={'href': re.compile("http")}):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

The output of which has many links, though none of the search result links that I am ultimately after.

Answer (score 0):

Those links are added with JavaScript, so `requests` is not suitable for processing the page. You can use Selenium instead. In addition, the links do not have href attributes that contain "http".

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
search_url = "https://www.dtcc.com/search?q=aggregated%20transaction%20data"
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
driver.get(search_url)
time.sleep(5)
for link in driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'search-results').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a'):
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

(You could also just use Selenium to get the page source after the JavaScript has been executed, then pass it to Beautiful Soup.)

Comment: This is great! Thanks @unmitigated. Follow up Q: Why does this script not grab all of the search links? Seems to grab only 10 of them when there is 103 I see. Trying to augment the script you provided to do this... Thanks again

Comment: You'd need to click on load more, it seems. @mkt_troglodyte

Comment: Ah. This might seem like a dumb question then, though how would I do that via this script / selenium? Or are you saying that it just isn't possible to get the full list this way? Thanks

Comment: You could do something like `driver.find_element(By.Class_NAME, 'next-text').click()` @mkt_troglodyte

Comment: You'll need to click multiple times to get all the results though. You might want to look into webdriver waits.